# JPA and classpath

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a JPA project and I am calling an external webservice

If I have this in my classpath

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/EclipseLink 2.5.2">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jpt.jpa"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

I have errors in my method

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.rmi.RemoteException: &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
```

If I remove this from my classpath, everything is working without any problem (but I guess no more JPA ?)
Could you help me fix this and understanding this ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Odd you tagged this as hibernate and JPA instead of the products involved; EclipseLink and Axis.  Can you get more details on the exception itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it, the solution is to move

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/EclipseLink 2.5.2">
<attributes>
    <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jpt.jpa"/>
</attributes>
```

at the end of the file .classpath (certainly as Robert said, both EclipseLink and Axis rely on a certain library)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You may have a dependency conflict in your project. It's possible that both EclipseLink and Axis rely on a certain library, but each depend on different, incompatible versions.